# Proper way to maintain Key to store value( STATE) in chaincode.?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, smartcontracts

Chain code basically store data in key-value pair(STATE).

If I have to store student data,I have to pass key-value e.g. 1001-{student info}. simply I can create any number of student.

But the problem is if student want to register dynamically. to manage it, student have to pass unique studentId or have to create dynamic key.?

Which is the proper way to implement this.?

Can anyone help me to understand this basic flow.?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Since you need to make sure that endorsement is consistent across endorsing peers, it's better that client, e.g. the application, will generate student id and will pass it into chaincode. Something along these line probably good way to go:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer"
)

// Student
type Person struct {
    ID      string `json:"id"`
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Faculty string `json:"faculty"`
    Address string `json:"address"`
}

// StudentAction
type StudentAction func(params []string, stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) peer.Response

// studentManagement the chaincode interface implementation to manage
// the ledger of person records
type studentManagement struct {
    actions map[string]StudentAction
}

// Init initialize chaincode with mapping between actions and real methods
func (pm *studentManagement) Init(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) peer.Response {
    pm.actions = map[string]StudentAction{
        "addStudent": pm.AddStudent,
    }

    fmt.Println("Chaincode has been initialized")
    fmt.Println("Following actions are available")
    for action := range pm.actions {
        fmt.Printf("\t\t%s\n", action)
    }
    return shim.Success(nil)
}

// Invoke handles chaincode invocation logic, executes actual code
// for given action name
func (pm *studentManagement) Invoke(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) peer.Response {
    actionName, params := stub.GetFunctionAndParameters()

    if action, ok := pm.actions[actionName]; ok {
        return action(params, stub)
    }

    return shim.Error(fmt.Sprintf("No <%s> action defined", actionName))
}

// AddStudent inserts new person into ledger
func (pm *personManagement) AddStudent(params []string, stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) peer.Response {
    jsonObj := params[0]
    var student Student

    // Read person info into struct
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonObj), &student)

    // Make uniqueness check 
    val, err := stub.GetState(student.ID)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("[ERROR] cannot get state, because of %s\n", err)
        return shim.Error(fmt.Sprintf("%s", err))
    }

    if val != nil {
        errMsg := fmt.Sprintf("[ERROR] student already exists, cannot create two accounts with same ID <%d>", student.ID)
        fmt.Println(errMsg)
        return shim.Error(errMsg)
    }

    fmt.Println("Adding new student", person)
    if err = stub.PutState(student.ID, []byte(jsonObj)); err != nil {
        errMsg := fmt.Sprintf("[ERROR] cannot store student record with id <%d>, due to %s", student.ID, err)
        fmt.Println(errMsg)
        return shim.Error(errMsg)
    }
    return shim.Success(nil)
}
```

and now once chaincode installed you can try adding new students with peer cli command in following way:

```
peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 \
                       -n students1 -v 1.0 -C exampleChannel \
                       -c '{"Args": ["addStudent”, "{ \"id\": \”12345678\”, \"Name\": \”John Doe\”, \”Faculty\”: \”Mathematics\”, \"address\": \”MIT\”}”]}’
```

Of course it's much more convenient with SDK.

Comment: Thanks Artem for helpful answer. 

But, In case I have to edit this student details I need id="12345678" to retrieve and update it. to do this I need 'id'

So should I have to store this Id anywhere.? Or any other approach you would like to suggest ?

Comment: if you would like to retrieve student record from the ledger, yes you have to provide unique identifier for that student. an alternative approach will be to send student name and another information and iterate over all students records. You can use range queries for that as an example.

Comment: so I can retrieve this record by name "John Doe". but It may be possible there is multiple student have name John Doe. 

How can i identify specific student without id.?

Comment: well, this is up to the application layer to be able to identify student. You have to have some unique id which will allow you to map 1:1 to students records, in fact same question will be valid in context of any database, not related to ledger and blockchain, this is purely business logic related your APIs and semantics.